# Does entry_points declared using [tool.poetry.dependencies] are supposed to be available in "sub-projects"

Tags: python-poetry

Let's say I have a project foo with:

```
[tools.poetry.scripts]
foo-cli = 'foo:main'
```

and a project bar with:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
bar = {path = "../foo"}
```

Is `foo-cli` supposed to be available in a virtualenv where bar is installed using `poetry install` (seems to not be the case so far) ?

Comment: That should work. But your dependency in project `bar` must look like this: `foo = {path = "../foo"}`

Comment: Yep that was a typo. Also it does not seems to work, poetry is `Poetry version 1.0.9` foo-cli is available inside the an envirnoment where i run `poetry install` inside the foo project, but not in an environment where i run  `poetry install` inside the bar project.

Comment: OK my bad I did a minimal example and it worked, It was not working for the project I'm working on  (started with an older version of poetry )though. I deleted/recreated the virtualenvs, and it fixed the issue. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project was started using an older version of poetry, remove and recreate the virtual envs fixed the issue.